# Passing Parameters to a Subreport

Tags: reporting-services

I have a main report that prompts the user to enter two parameters (@ORI and @CaseNumber). Within this report, I have a subreport that needs to pass a value that is picked up by the main report (@Sequence). How do I pass the value that the main report contains to the subreport? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the cell with Navigation and choose Properties. Click the Navigation tab. In the Hyperlink action section where it says Jump to Report click the Parameters button. This shows the parameters of the linked report and allows you toput expressions of what values you want to pass. To pass a parameter value, put in something like:

```
=Parameters!MyParameter.Value
```