# How to create subreport RDLC in winform of VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, rdlc

Does any one who know how to create subreport calling from main report with passing parameters to subreport.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following links:

[Passing Parameters to a Subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938358/passing-parameters-to-a-subreport)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581.aspx